# objective-c identifying contentView items

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

Is there a way to identify unique objects within the contentView? For example, I in my mainWin I have a NSView and 2 NSButtons. Using

```
[[mainWin contentView] subviews];
```

I can get all the objects within the mainWin. This works fine for my needs if the object is a subclass of NSView and I've given it a class, for example, in this case I've named the class vHUD and when I log the object it comes back as

```
<vHUD: 0x146e10>
```

This is fine for NSViews I am creating because for the most part if I am making them they are going to serve multiple purposes (content container, being toggled around screen, etc.) and a class should be necessary. I could subclass all the buttons (under NSObject) and go that way, but it seems like a sledgehammer approach if I end up having a lot of buttons. Is there a way I can uniquely identify all of the buttons with something descriptive in IB that can then be retrieved from the object itself? I tried "description" but that didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the tag instance variable in the NSView class?

Comment: yes, I've been able to read that but it needs to be an index number, I was hoping for something more descriptive. I guess I could set all the tags and then create a dictionary where the keys are the tag indexes and the values the descriptive if needs be, but it seems like more work than I should need to do...

Comment: what i was hoping for was a simple way to retrieve the var name you apply to the IB Outlet - for example I use this naming convention - all views are vViewName - like this vHUD (head up display) and all buttons are btnButtonName. So in my app controller they are listed as such: IBOutlet id vHUD; IBOutlet id btnCloseHUD, etc and I've linked them to the proper objects in IB. Now I made a class for vHUD so I am able to see it when I get all the subviews but there has to be a way I can get the names I've assigned to the IBOutlets, shouldn't there?

Comment: Solved it (at least for views and buttons) - use the alternate title for buttons, class for subviews and some conditional kung-fu to sort it all out

Comment: Anyone know why you can set description in IB, call it on your object, for example a table named myTable - [myTable description] but get this returned in the log - <NSScrollView: 0x1369c0> - I guess the description in IB and the description in objective-c are not related?